# How to disable all Nagios notifications if a specific alert goes off

Tags: nagios

I created a script that monitors a Cisco Router interface.

```
./check_cisco Router1 Serial0/0/0
Interface Serial0/0/0 is up for Router1
```

I would like to stop all other notifications if a critical or warning alert is trigged for this alert.  Not really sure how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to look into the dependencies system of nagios.

See http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/dependencies.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid warnings for hosts behind the router interface when it is down, you could simply use the "parents" option on the hosts behind it. This tells nagios that whenever the router is unavailable there is no use in checking the stuff behind it.

Adding "parents" to all your hosts has the added benefit that the status map becomes much more useful.

```
define host{
    use             generic-host
    host_name       cisco_router
    alias           Important router
    address         192.168.1.228
    check_command   check_cisco
}

define host{
    use             generic-host
    host_name       office_printer
    alias           A printer
    address         192.168.1.250
    parents         cisco_router
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add the appropriate parents entry to the hostgroup that they are a part of, rather than each host entry?

Comment: If the hostgroup is really a group of hardware behind the router, sure. But it's probably more likely you will have a group like "printers" or "access points", where the objects are spread out.